# Replacing a string in Google Protocol Data Buffers

Tags: java, google-app-engine, serialization, protocol-buffers

I've succesfully built the following .proto file:

```
package JervisStorage;

option java_package = "TextBase";
option java_outer_classname = "JervisStorage";

message Owner {
  optional string name = 1;
  optional string sex = 2;
  optional string profession = 3;
  optional string email = 4;
}
```

Now, I managed to build the Owner:

```
private static Owner owner;
private static FileOutputStream serialOutput;

Owner pusheen= Owner.newBuilder()
                .setName("Siema") 
                .setSex(" ") 
                .setProfession(" ")
                .setEmail(" ")
                .build();
```

I wrote the object to the file and successfully read the object from the file:

```
serialOutput = new FileOutputStream("JervisStorage.ser");
pusheen.writeTo(serialOutput);
serialOutput.close();

owner = Owner.parseFrom(new FileInputStream("JervisStorage.ser"));
System.out.println(owner.getName());
```

The problem is that I am unable to replace a signle record, write it back to the file and read the whole updated object. I have been trying to do this:

```
owner.toBuilder().setName("newName").build();
System.out.println(owner.getName());
serialOutput = new  FileOutputStream("JervisStorage.ser");
owner.writeTo(serialOutput);
serialOutput.close();

owner = Owner.parseFrom(new FileInputStream("JervisStorage.ser"));
System.out.println(owner.getName());
```

Unfortunately, this approach does not seem to work... Can anyone help?

Comment: When you say `owner.toBuilder()`, it creates a builder, but it does *not* mutate the existing entity.  You need to assign the result of the call to build(), since it's a new instance.  Think immutable types. See the "Builders" section of https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not do

```
  editedOwner = Owner.newBuilder()
                          .mergeFrom(new FileInputStream("JervisStorage.ser")) 
                          .setName("new name") 
                          .build();
```

alternatively you could do

```
  editedOwner = owner.toBuilder()
                     .setName("new name") 
                     .build();
```

Comment: There is no method .mergerFrom, perhaps my library is outdated. I have tried the second approach, please look above.

Comment: Sorry, typing error, should be mergeFrom and nor mergerFrom. I have updated my answer

Comment: The first suggestion works, I like it. Thank you very much Bruce :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to find a solution to this problem. I hate extending the computation time when unnecessary, but this is the best I can think of so far. I've got two Owner objects: owner and editedOwner:

```
Owner owner;//for reading the records from the file
Owner editedOwner;// for addidng to the file

owner = Owner.parseFrom(new FileInputStream("JervisStorage.ser"));

editedOwner = Owner.newBuilder()
                            .setName("new name") 
                            .setSex(owner.getSex()) 
                            .setProfession(owner.getProfession())
                            .setEmail(owner.getEmail())
                            .build();

serialOutput = new FileOutputStream("JervisStorage.ser");
editedOwner.writeTo(serialOutput);
serialOutput.close();
```

Fortunately, this little messy approach solves my problem for now. Thank you.